# Incorrect adding of checkbox value per row in the database

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox, mysqli

I want to insert the correct value for checkbox for each row. See this

[image: Picture 1],

but when I try to hit submit button, the data repeats depending on the last checkbox that I've checked. See this

[image: Picture 2].

Here are my codes for reference.

```
<?php

include 'database.php';
session_start();
 if(isset($_POST['save']))
  { 
    $plant_id = $_POST['plant_id'];
    $workplace_id = $_POST['workplace_id'];
    $checklistSQL = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM checklist WHERE plant_id = 
    '$plant_id' AND workplace_id = '$workplace_id' ");
        while($cdata = $checklistSQL->fetch_assoc())
      {
      $checklist = $cdata['checklist']; 
      $answer = $_POST['answer'];
      $remarks = $_POST['remarks'];
      $insertSQL = $connect->query("INSERT INTO report(checklist, answer, remarks) VALUES ('$checklist', '$answer', '$remarks') ");
      }
   }
 ?>

<?php
        $checklistSQL = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM checklist WHERE plant_id = '$plant_id' AND workplace_id = '$workplace_id' ");
        while($cdata = $checklistSQL->fetch_assoc())
        {
          $checklist = $cdata['checklist']; 
          ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $checklist ?></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="yes" <?php if(isset ($_POST['yes'])){ echo "Yes";  } ?> /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="no" <?php if(isset($_POST['no'])) { echo "No"; } ?> /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="n/a" <?php if(isset($_POST['n/a'])) { echo "N/A"; } ?> /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="remarks" class="remarks" placeholder"Remarks"/></td>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.

Comment: The problem is with the 3 statements like $_POST['yes']. I don't see any inputs named 'yes'. Echo the $_POST array to see what data is being sent from the form. ```echo "<p>\$_POST:<pre>".print_r($_POST,true)."</pre></p>\n";```

Comment: Are you storing booleans as yes/no text? It is much better to store them as booleans.

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection**. 
And The issue is here:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="yes" <?php if(isset ($_POST['yes'])){ echo "Yes";  } ?> /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="no" <?php if(isset($_POST['no'])) { echo "No"; } ?> /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="answer" value="n/a" <?php if(isset($_POST['n/a'])) { echo "N/A"; } ?> /></td>
```

all these checkboxes have the common name `answer`, so the last checkbox selection over write the previous selected values. So make the name as an array like:

`answer[]` so that it can hold multiple values in it. And iterate over 
`answer[]` to get all values.

Comment: This is only part of the problem. The OP also refers to non-existant post parameters 'yes', 'no' and 'n/a' instead of the fields being submitted.

Comment: The problem is related to that only

Comment: I agree with the issue you point out in your answer, but will ```isset($_POST['yes'])``` ever be true, even after switching to an array? No.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the use of a radio element as opposed to checkboxes from a UI perspective.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

But, if you would like checkboxes you would need to adjust the "name" attribute to be an array to gather the data you are looking for. And in PHP, be prepared to capture the data back as an array.

HTML

```
name="answer[]"
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will change it later, if we can fix this issue :) Regarding to your suggestion, I tried to make the checkbox name as an array that looks like this 'name="answer[]"' but when I save it, it shows "Array" value in the database so that I used the implode function, though I got the correct array value, but it will appear the value on the same row. Kindly check this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtVFQ.jpg What codes/functions do I need to add?

Comment: Best practice would be to loop through the array. foreach($_POST['answer'] as $val) { $answer = $val); } , if your end goal is to have several rows of checklist items I might recommend appending a numeric ID to each HTML form field. As an example you would have answer1 answer2 etc and then when you receive the post data, loop through the total number of questions and determine the appropriate answer to the question to insert.

Comment: That worked for checkbox value! Thank you! However, the statement of those questions now be repeated. Kindly check this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cm8cr.jpg


Here's my added code so you can check on what I've missed out.

`while($cdata = $checklistSQL->fetch_assoc())
      {
      $checklist = $cdata['checklist']; 
      $answer = $_POST['answer'];
      $remarks = $_POST['remarks'];
      foreach($answer as $result) {
       $insertSQL = $connect->query("INSERT INTO report(checklist, answer, remarks) VALUES ('$checklist', '$result', '$remarks') ");
       }
    }`

Comment: Put the foreach before the insert statement, only use it to assign the answer value. As an example: $answer = ""; foreach($answer as $result) { $dbanswer = $answer; } use dbanswer to insert into the DB

Comment: Thanks for your response again, I put the foreach function before the insert statement (Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rE13A.jpg ), but the answer (checkbox) value does not properly added to the database (Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNuAc.jpg ) as the $answer is equal to "" (I assumed). I'm sorry, I'm new to PHP. I appreciate your help on this part @Matt.

Comment: If I put the insert SQL command outside the foreach function based on the screenshot that you've shown (Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6sNt.jpg ) the value of the checkbox was not properly added https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbz7C.jpg , but when I put the insert SQL command inside the foreach (Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6jmH.jpg ) the sequence of the checkbox value was properly stored but the questions still repeated depending on the number of checkbox value being stored, screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsnf3.jpg